# How to automatically populate missing values in a column with R

Tags: r

I have data with gaps in it. The value increases as you go down the column and I want a way to be able to replace missing values with values that follow the sequence of increasing numbers depending on the values before and after the gap. here is an example of how the data looks at the moment, how do I fill these gaps?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 7.235 | Cell 2 |
| 7.235 | Cell 4 |
|  | Cell 2 |
|  | Cell 4 |
| 7.236 | Cell 2 |
| 7.236 | Cell 4 |

I am not sure where to start with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  Also, your question is inconsistent.  Your sequence is not "increasing" (though it is monotone).  How do you want the gaps filled, particularly when you have two or more consecutive rows with missing values?  Please provide your expected output based on your test data, along with an explanation of how values should be derived.